# Small or Superfluous submodule

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Suppose $A$ is a summand of an $R$-module $M$ and take any $P \leq M=A \oplus B$ such that $P \nleq A$, $A \nleq P$, $P \nleq B$, $B \nleq P$, $(A+P) \cap B \nleq P$ and $(A+P) \cap B \nleq A$. Is it true that
 $(A+P) \cap B \leq_{S} A+P\ ?$

Comment: What part are you having trouble with?

Comment: Thank you sir @Bernard for correcting the word "Superfluous". I am unable to show that $[(A+P) \cap B] + K = A+ P$ implies that $K= A + P$. I could proceed up to $ P \leq [(A+P) \cap B] + K = A+ P= K + P$.

Answer (score 0):

Here $(A+P) \cap B \nleq_{S} A+P$. If $(A+P) \cap B \leq_{S} A+P$ then $ A+P=A$ which implies $P \leq A$.